# what is the registration no for the Certification of Micro Entity Status form

Tags: patent-applications, micro-entity

I am filing the [CERTIFICATION OF MICRO ENTITY STATUS](https://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/forms/sb0015a.pdf) form. But I don't know where to get the Registration No., which is at the end of the form.

**Edit:**

I am doing it by myself for provisional.

Comment: Regarding the "I am doing it by myself for provisional." I hope you know that the effective protection you're getting by that is very small. It's not possible to *just correct* stuff at the non-provisional phase without losing the priority date.

Comment: PTO/SB/15A /15B Form Registration No. is the registration number of the patent agent.
Not an inventor application number.

Comment: @YinhuaJin I made your answer into a comment since it didn't actually answer the question. As you gain reputation points, you'll gain the ability to comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you processing your application through a patent agent or you are processing your own application??

For our company patent applications, the patent agent registration number is being filled in the form. I assume that column applies only when a patent agent is processing the application.

The below is the description quoted from [USPTO](https://www.uspto.gov/patent/forms/who-may-sign-forms-ptosb15a-and-15b)

The certification of micro entity status forms (Forms PTO/SB/15A and PTO/SB/15B) may only be signed by an authorized party as set forth in 37 CFR 1.33(b).  This means that the only parties who may sign a certification of micro entity status form are:

1. A registered patent practitioner, meaning a registered attorney or agent who is either of record or acting in a representative capacity under 37 CFR 1.34;
2. An inventor who is named as the sole inventor and identified as the applicant; or
3. All of the joint inventors who are identified as the applicant.

If qualified for micro entity status, joint inventor applicants should sign separate copies of the relevant micro entity certification form(s).
An officer of an assignee corporation or organization is not authorized to sign a certification of micro entity status form.

Comment: Yes, I am doing it by myself for the provisional.

Comment: @peterboston if you are proceeding for the provisional by your self then it is not mandatory i think, see PROVISIONAL APPLICATION FOR PATENT COVER SHEET https://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/documents/sb0016.pdf in page 2 the registration no (is if  appropriate)

Comment: if you are a private person, you probably fall in category 2, so you should be able to sign it by yourself